# Cache-control: private and public

Tags: http, web-standards, cache-control, rfc2616

What should a http client do if server returned `Cache-Control: private, public` ?

I have a feeling `private` should override `public`, but I can't find a confirmation in the RFC (other than `MUST` in `private` and `MAY` in `public`).

Comment: For reference, [RFC 2616: 14.9.1 What is Cacheable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1). It's up to the browser how it should be handled. So, do not send both `public` and `private`.

Comment: I am making a client, not server, and I am thinking in advance how to handle these scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pragmatic point of view, err on the side of caution and treat it "private".

That way you cause a little extra network traffic for the lousy server, but keep your user's (potentially private) data safe.

Answer (score 5):

I believe http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-20.html#rfc.section.3 is pretty clear -- if it's labeled "private" it needs to be considered private, no matter whether "public" appears as well

Comment: Is this official yet?

Comment: Pacerier: what yo you mean by "official"? No, it's not published as a RFC yet. See http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/wiki#HTTP1.1Deliverables

Comment: Hmm, is it going to be finalized for release soon?

Comment: It will need to got through an IETF Last Call (soonish), then likely revised once again, then be approved by the IESG.

Answer (score 1):

Private cache control is used in this context to cache and store the data for a single user machine and not to be served with the entire network.

Whereas the Public Cache control is used to store the data in the client machine from the server and share it across the network on which the client machine is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Private cache control is used in this context to cache and store the data for a single user machine and not to be served with the entire network.

Whereas the Public Cache control is used to store the data in the client machine from the server and share it across the network on which the client machine is connected to.

Please refer the below example contains the details of http://www.totalworkflow.co.uk/ Server response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: .ASPXANONYMOUS=TV4owqs-zQEkAAAAZmFhNDI5NDQtZmFmMi00Y2Q3LWI4NDctYTE0NDg5MzAwNjg20; expires=Wed, 30-May-2012 21:32:48 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=x12csr3ac4jp03jugqawke2d; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.5072
```